# Python deep nesting factory functions

Tags: python, function, factory

Working through "Learning Python" came across factory function. This textbook example works:

```
def maker(N):
    def action(X):
        return X ** N
    return action


>>> maker(2)
<function action at 0x7f9087f008c0>
>>> o = maker(2)
>>> o(3)
8
>>> maker(2)
<function action at 0x7f9087f00230>
>>> maker(2)(3)
8
```

However when going deeper another level I have no idea how to call it:

```
>>> def superfunc(X):
...     def func(Y):
...             def subfunc(Z):
...                     return X + Y + Z
...     return func
... 
>>> superfunc()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: superfunc() takes exactly 1 argument (0 given)
>>> superfunc(1)
<function func at 0x7f9087f09500>
>>> superfunc(1)(2)
>>> superfunc(1)(2)(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
>>> superfunc(1)(2)
>>>
```

Why doesn't `superfunc(1)(2)(3)` work while `maker(2)(3)` does?

While this kind of nesting certainly doesn't look like a good, usable code to me, Python still accepts it as valid, so I'm curious as to how this can be called.

Comment: It looks better if you only indent by 4 spaces instead of 8.

Comment: `superfunc(1)(2)` returns None, and then you invoked (3) on that,i.e. None(3), which raises the Error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a `TypeError` because function `func` doesn't return anything (thus its return is `NoneType`). It should return `subfunc`:

```
>>> def superfunc(X):
...     def func(Y):
...             def subfunc(Z):
...                     return X + Y + Z
...             return subfunc
...     return func
...
```

Comment: Indeed, forgetting return statement is embarassing :) I should have guessed it by the  None that functions return by default.

Answer (score 2):

A return is missing somewhere in your `superfunc`: you have a `return` for `subfunc`, but none for `func`.

Answer (score 2):

superfunc corrected, with a calling example

```
def superfunc(X):
    def func(Y):
        def subfunc(Z):
            return X + Y + Z
        return subfunc
    return func

print superfunc(1)(2)(3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot the return of the second function.
Here is the fixed function

```
def superfunct(x):
  def func(y):
    def subfunc(z):
      return x + y + z
    return subfunc
  return func

print superfunct(1)(2)(3)
```