# Python Factory Function

Tags: python

Same example from the same book: [Python deep nesting factory functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12687277/python-deep-nesting-factory-functions)

```
def maker(N):
    def action(X):
        return X ** N 
    return action
```

I understand the concept behind it and i think it's really neat but I cant seem to envision when I could use this approach.

I could have easily implement the above by having `maker()` take both N and X as an argument instead.

Has anyone use this type of factory function and explain to me why you went this approach instead of just taking multiple arguments?

Is it just user preference?

Comment: "Same" compared to what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
squarer = maker(2)

print(squarer(2)) # outputs 4
print(squarer(4)) # outputs 16
print(squarer(8)) # outputs 64
```

Essentially, it means you only have to enter in the `N` value once and then you can't change it later.

I think it's mostly programming style as there are multiple ways of doing the same thing.  However, this way you can only enter the `N` value once so you could add code to test that it's a valid value once instead of checking each time you called the function.

**EDIT**
just thought of a possible example (though it's usually handled by using a class):

```
writer = connectmaker("127.0.0.1")
writer("send this text")
writer("send this other text")
```

The "maker" method would then connect to the address once and then maintain that value for each call to `writer()`.  But as I said, something like this is usually a class where the `__init__` would store the values.

Comment: `**` is not multiplication, so the name `doubler` is wrong, and so are the given results. Nevertheless, +1 for meaning the right thing.

Comment: doh!  changed it to `squarer`

Comment: yeah i see it better now with the connectmaker example.

Answer (score 1):

In a certain way, you can see some of the `operator` function as these as well.

For example, `operator.itemgetter()` works this way:

```
import operator
get1 = operator.itemgetter(1) # creates a function which gets the item #1 of the given object
get1([5,4,3,2,1]) # gives 4
```

This is often used e. g. as a `key=` function of sorting functions and such.

Similiar, more dedicated use cases are easily imaginable if you have a concrete problem which you can solve with that.

In the same league you have these "decorator creators":

```
def indirect_deco(outer_param):
    def real_deco(func):
        def wrapper(*a, **k):
            return func(outer_param, *a, **k)
        return wrapper
    return real_deco

@indirect_deco(1)
def function(a, b, c):
    print (((a, b, c))

function(234, 432)
```

Here as well, the outer function is a factory function which creates the "real deco" function. This, in turn, even creates another oner which replaces the originally given one.

Comment: yes i understand that but why is that better than just having get(1,[5,4,3,2,1])? just so that i dont have to pass in 1 all the time?

Comment: @ealeon It completely depends on the use case whether you need it or not. Maybe it serves as a mere simplification; maybe it is absolutely needed because you have to adapt the interface.