# NoneType object is not callable in nested function python

Tags: python-3.x

I am beginner to Python, i am trying this follwing code but i cant understand the error

```py
def make(label):
    def echo(message):
        print(label+':'+message) 


make('Message')('Hi')
```

I expect the output to be `Message:Hi` but it showing an error `'NoneType object is not callable`

Comment: This is called a factory function. You have to return the function you create, which is `echo` in this case. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19548164/python-factory-function

Answer (score 2):

you need to return the echo function

```py
def make(label):
    def echo(message):
        print(label+':'+message) 
    return echo

make('Message')('Hi')
```